# Update Sales Force DB with Docusign Envelope ID using Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

Team,
I'm using the demo version of docusign API in my web application (test), 
I have updated the connect functionality to connect to the salesforce in the demo account that i have. I need to understand how can I update the envelope status to sales force for the opportunity Im writing the contract for.

Steps
1 The user logs into our website 
2 Clicks the DocuSign link (i call the demo API to show the docusign website in an IFrame)
3 The user is an Opportunity in salesforce
3 Depending upon the User response I show a final message page.

need to do.
Apart form the mails i receive, I want to update the docusign section for that user(oppurtinuity) in sales force. Our salesforce database is connected to the docusign.

Please do let me know if you need any other details. Appreciate your help.

Comment: This issue is resolved, just add the following code./n   envelopeInfo.CustomFields = new CustomField[] { 
                new CustomField { Name = "##SFAccount", Value = account.Id,Show="",Required="" }, 
                new CustomField { Name = "##SFContract", Value = contact.Id,Show="",Required="" }, 
                new CustomField { Name = "##SFOpportunity", Value = opportunity.Id,Show="",Required="" } };

Comment: Can you create an actual answer out of your comment so it's obvious that there's a solution for this??  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code:

```
envelopeInfo.CustomFields = new CustomField[] { 
    new CustomField { 
        Name = "##SFAccount", 
        Value = account.Id,
        Show="",
        Required="" 
        }, 
        new CustomField { 
            Name = "##SFContract", 
            Value = contact.Id,
            Show="",
            Required="" 
        }, 
        new CustomField { 
            Name = "##SFOpportunity", 
            Value = opportunity.Id,
            Show="",Required="" 
        } 
};
```